# Ecommerce site Screaming Frog (and other tools) crawls return internal cart urls with parameters

Tags: screaming-frog

**Example url:** somedomaindotcom/patches-metal-rubber-1-can/?add-to-cart=4183

When I crawl my WooCommerce sites with tools like Screaming Frog/AHREFS/SEMRush they return these one-time usage urls that seem to me to indicate that I have configured my sites incorrectly or, I need to configure my crawls within these tools to exclude these urls. Which is the case?

The urls in question are Non-Indexable & Canonicalized correctly. I want to know why crawls return those and is it a misconfiguration on my part? It seems that if a crawler crawled every historic cart page like this then the crawls would grow ever longer and eventually become unwieldy.

[image]

Comment: Does it show which page it is discovering those URLs from?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I don't see a page of origin but I see a lot of tabbed information within SF related to these urls that I must investigate because of your suggestion. Thanks.